# ffmpeg - получить 9 кадров из видео

Tags: ffmpeg

```
[0:v]fps=1/".($time/9)."
```

Для того, чтобы получить 9 кадров из видео. Вынужден предварительно запрашивать продолжительность ролика, затем полученное число делим на 9 и получаем интервал через который выхватываем кадры.

Вопрос в том, возможно ли выполнить тоже самое. Предварительно, не запрашивая информацию и продолжительности.

То есть избавится от данной операции, дабы сократить время задержки на получение кадров?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i <input> -vf "select=eq(n\,32)" -vframes 1 33.png` - нарисовали 33й кадр в 33.png . Взято отсюда https://superuser.com/a/1010108

Comment: 33 кадр, не совсем понимаю. А если 1000 кадров в видео,  мне выдаст 32 кадра вместо 9?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, в ffmpeg нет переменной для того что бы получить длительность (https://video.stackexchange.com/q/35062). Как варант могу предложить сделать `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf select='not(mod(n\,300))',setpts=N/TB -r 1 -vframes 9 fames%03d.png`, но такой вариант возмёт первые 9 кадров с промежутком в 300 (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35913395/14168867).  Если волнует именно время обработки, возможно стоит самому посчитать номера нужных кадров и указать их `select='eq(n\,1)+eq(n\,10)+eq(n\,19)'`.

Comment: изучая данную тему узнал что если не конвертировать в jpeg то время сокращается предлагается записывать в `bmp` - так как это в каком-то смысле `raw`, надеюсь будет полезно

Comment: А как запрашиваете продолжительность? По идее, если делать это через `ffprobe`, то задержка должна быть очень маленькой и, возможно, это решит проблему.

Comment: Как минимум можно еще попробовать распараллеливание работы

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов извините, пропустил, то есть вам нужно понизить fps видео? Это можно понять, только прочитав вопрос 5 раз - пишите в след. раз зачем вам оно. Там есть параметр `-r` для этого.